# Upgrade OpenSSH, OpenSSL, PHP, Apache on Ubuntu 7.10 LTS Hardy Heron

Tags: apt

I'm trying to upgrade my versions of the above packages to meet PCI compliance.
I ran apt-get upgrade and almost all of them upgraded but the version numbers stayed the same. Ubuntu 7.10 is Long Term Support so I assume there are these newer patched version available but I can't find them in the official repos.

Comment: That isn't a programming question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like LTS doesn't mean they support newer code. I had to upgrade.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you have Hardy desktop edition and the LTS is for server edition only

edit: and I agree with Pointy that this is not a programming question and should be on Super User I guess